# Get error when installing Zend Framework in ubuntu with virtual host

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, installation, virtual-hosts

I have troubles to install zend framework in ubuntu 12.04 with virtual host and get the first screen.

1) I have installed zend framework executing sudo apt-get install zend-framework-bin
2) In my folder /home/kostas/develop/ I execute zf create project test
3) In my **/etc/hosts** file I have 127.0.0.1   test
4) in my /etc/apache2/site-available/test I have the following:

```
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias test
    DocumentRoot /home/kostas/develop/test/public/
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
```

I restart the apache, doesn't work! White browser screen!

Can someone help me?

**SOLUTION!!!**
1) first of all we need to see apache2 errors which means: /var/log/apache2/error.log
2) we should enable rewrite mode which means: 
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
3) we should add the folder library/Zend which is located in Zend Framework tar.gz file that we have downloaded from zend.com in the library folder of our project, in my case: 
/home/kostas/develop/test/library
4) we may give correct rights of test folder -R in any case.

That's all! Is working!

Comment: "White browser screen" just means there's an error that isn't being shown. Check the error log to see what the error is.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps, http://www.mrxuri.com/2013/08/05/install-zend-framework-on-linux-ubuntu.html, http://samitrimal.blogspot.com/2012/12/installing-zend-framework-2-in-ubuntu.html. Check out this tutorials as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION!!!**
1) first of all we need to see apache2 errors which means: /var/log/apache2/error.log
2) we should enable rewrite mode which means: 
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
3) we should add the folder library/Zend which is located in Zend Framework tar.gz file that we have downloaded from zend.com in the library folder of our project, in my case: 
/home/kostas/develop/test/library
4) we may give correct rights of test folder -R in any case.

That's all! Is working!

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to make sure that error reporting is turned in your php.ini then maybe you're screen will show some errors.

You could also try removing those options beneath the SetEnv line and adding this to that config file and see if that helps. It's similar to what I have running on Ubuntu with ZF right now.

```
<Directory /home/kostas/develop/test/public/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```